# SSL jdbc connection fails with Diffie-Hellman (DH_ANON) cipher suites

Tags: ssl, encryption, jdbc, oracle11g, diffie-hellman

I am trying create an SSL enabled connection to the Oracle database 11g (Release 11.2.0.1.0) using jdbc. I just want to use SSL for encryption only and not authentication, which is why I am using the Diffie-Hellman anonymous cipher suites, but it is failing.

I totally understand that anonymous cipher suites are not advisable and inherently insecure against man-in-the-middle attacks and probably I will not use it in production. But I would still like to find out what is wrong with my implementation that is preventing the ssl connection. Following is the excerpt of the code

```
    String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=<IP>)(PORT=2484))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=<service_name>)) )";
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("user", "hr");
    props.setProperty("password", "hr");
    props.setProperty("oracle.net.ssl_cipher_suites",    "(SSL_DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, SSL_DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA)");

    // commented out since Diffie-Hellman cipher suite should not require trust store or key-store, but the connection works only if I uncomment it.
    //props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "/truststore/cwallet.sso");
    //props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "SSO");

    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        //Security.insertProviderAt(new oracle.security.pki.OraclePKIProvider(),3);
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
        System.out.println("conn " + conn);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

IN sqlnet.ora I added the following to make sure client is not authenticated and client server uses the same cipher suite:

```
SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION = FALSE
SSL_CIPHER_SUITES=(SSL_DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,SSL_DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5,SSL_DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA)
```

However when I run the code I get the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:419)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:538)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:228)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
  at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
  at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:154)
  at oracle.bi.modeling.Test.createConnection(Test.java:50)
  at oracle.bi.modeling.Test.main(Test.java:18)
    Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
  at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:375)
  at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:422)
  at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:686)
  at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:246)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1056)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:308)
  ... 8 more
    Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Unable to initialize ssl context.
  at oracle.net.nt.CustomSSLSocketFactory.getSSLSocketFactory(CustomSSLSocketFactory.java:327)
  at oracle.net.nt.TcpsNTAdapter.connect(TcpsNTAdapter.java:110)
  at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:130)
  at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:353)
  ... 13 more
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Unable to initialize the trust store.
  at oracle.net.nt.CustomSSLSocketFactory.getTrustManagerArray(CustomSSLSocketFactory.java:415)
  at oracle.net.nt.CustomSSLSocketFactory.getSSLSocketFactory(CustomSSLSocketFactory.java:311)
  ... 16 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
  at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:771)
  at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:38)
  at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1185)
  at oracle.net.nt.CustomSSLSocketFactory.getTrustManagerArray(CustomSSLSocketFactory.java:406)
  ... 17 more
    Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed
  at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:769)
  ... 20 more
```

If do specify the trust store, then the connection works fine when I uncomment the following lines:

```
props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "/truststore/cwallet.sso");
props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "SSO");
```

But Diffie-Hellman cipher suite should not require truststore or keystore. So what am I doing wrong?

I do see the following in one of oracle docs:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28530/asossl.htm#i1009717

"There is a known bug in which an OCI client requires a wallet even when using a cipher suite with DH_ANON, which does not authenticate the client."

However I am not using OCI client. Instead I am using JDBC (ojdbc6.jar). Does the same exist even in JDBC? If so what is the work around to use Diffie-Hellman cipher suite?

Thanks

Joyjit

Comment: Do you use other global `javax.net.ssl.trustStore`, `javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword` and `javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType` settings (I mean system properties instead of your local properties) anywhere before that (either as VM parameters or in your code)?

Comment: Thanks Bruno. Thats exactly what it was. I was running this java program from jdeveloper with integrated weblogic, and somehow jdeveloper was adding a demo trust store to the to the system variable when I run this java program. After I cleared this  system property it worked fine. Thanks again.